# Can't Find PHP Script as Running Process on Linux Operating System?

Tags: php, linux, process, ps

I have a PHP file on my Amazon Linux that looks like

```
<?php

sleep(600);
```

I run the file by hitting a publicly available URL.  When the file is running, I run

```
ps aux
```

on my Linux box, but I can't find the corresponding process from the list.  I've also tried

```
ps ax | grep *.php
```

which returns no results.

Why am I not able to find my PHP process?

Comment: Because you're probably running PHP inside apache, which means you'll only see Apache's children, never PHP itself. You'd have to look at open files and find whichever `httpd` child has your .php script file open.

Comment: Is it actually a process and do you have a script that just runs. So, when you run your ps command it is all after the fact? Do you have it as a cron running every 1 minute?

Comment: @MarcB What's the command to look at open files within httpd?

Comment: `fuser`, if it's installed

Comment: you can use this command: sudo lsof -c httpd this shows files open by name. The -c option searches for a pattern

Answer (score 1):

Just issue this command

```
 ps aux | grep php
```

don't issue `*.php`

I just did `ps aux | grep php` on my box and I got the following output

```
ps aux | grep php
root      6156  0.0  0.1 189700  4128 pts/9    T    12:00   0:00 sudo emacs MissionAgreement.php -nw
root      6168  0.1  0.4 252820 16864 pts/9    T    12:00   0:02 emacs MissionAgreement.php -nw
gain-dev  6387  0.0  0.1 230632  4640 ?        Sl   12:13   0:00 /usr/lib64/libreoffice/program/oosplash --writer /var/www/html/wwwroot/phpword/samples/gain_docx_template/MissionAgreement_.docx
gain-dev  6400  4.1  6.0 1515164 237840 ?      Sl   12:13   0:45 /usr/lib64/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin --writer /var/www/html/wwwroot/phpword/samples/gain_docx_template/MissionAgreement_.docx --splash-pipe=6
gain-dev  6869  0.0  0.0 103252   828 pts/9    S+   12:32   0:00 grep php
root     20355  0.0  0.0 189700     8 pts/9    T    Dec19   0:00 sudo emacs Invoice.php -nw
root     20483  0.0  0.0 252612     8 pts/9    T    Dec19   0:01 emacs Invoice.php -nw
gain-dev 29811  0.0  0.2 404620 10492 ?        S    Dec18   1:54 gedit /home/gain-dev/.cache/.fr-HxN35J/index.php
root     30741  0.0  0.0 189704     8 pts/0    T    Dec16   0:00 sudo emacs gain_fns.php -nw
root     30743  0.0  0.0 252288     8 pts/0    T    Dec16   0:00 emacs gain_fns.php -nw
root     31164  0.0  0.0 189700     8 pts/0    T    Dec16   0:00 sudo emacs /etc/php.ini -nw
root     31174  0.0  0.0 250640     8 pts/0    T    Dec16   0:00 emacs /etc/php.ini -nw
root     31380  0.0  0.0 189704     8 pts/0    S    Dec16   0:00 sudo emacs mission_insert.php -nw
root     31382  0.0  0.3 252664 12464 pts/0    S+   Dec16   0:01 emacs mission_insert.php -nw
```

If the example above is an issue, you can alternatively enable mod_status with ExtendedStatus on will show the pids and URLs that is currently being processed. You'll get a nice output and an example on this url: http://www.apache.org/server-status